# Why is the ArcMap IDW tool interpolating values higher that it's closest data points

Tags: raster, arcmap, interpolation, inverse-distance-weighted

I have a dataset of equally spaced, by 3 arcseconds, points.  Each point represents the radio signal strength from a near by transmitter.  I wanted to convert the point data set into a raster for better visual analysis.  I  used the IDW (spatial analyst) tool, expecting that a cell between points would interpolate a value somewhere between the two values, but not greater or less both.
In the picture below I'm using IDW on the point set that's visible.  I set it to consider 4 data points and use variable radius.  If you look at the picture, where the pixel inspector is, the cell that i'm pointing to is close to 4 other points for which I pasted the value in the picture.  I expected that to get the value of that cell that the tool would consider the value of the 4 closest points and take the weighted average of the 4 which would be somewhere between -157.1 and -148.1, but the value the tool is giving is -106.03778.  So where is that value coming from?
I using the wrong tool for what I want?

[image]

[image]

This is the identify all layers output from the same project.  It has the IDW set up to evaluate based on 4 of the closest points, also I created an INT layer out of the idw layer.  I used the identify tool and sampled a "square" of 4 data points then the top output is taken in the center of the "square.

[image]

Comment: Can you run INT on the output raster for me and check the value again? Then just use identify and not the pixel inspector. I do not trust the pixel inspector.

Comment: OK.  I ran INT, and I edited my original question with the output of the Identify from all layers.  I took samples from 4 points as the corners of a square and then from the center of the square. I'm seeing the same issue.

Comment: Also, I just realized that my input point feature has values from -54 to -287, but my IDW output only has values from -54 to about -112.  Looking back at the "results" tab, I used the correct point feature as my input.  But, I remember that previously I did a select on that layer for values > -112 and exported that as a layer, but with a different name, so I'm not using that by mistake.  Would the IDW tool possibly be only using selected values if I didn't clear out the selected values explicitly? I restarted arcmap and ran IWD several times with same results though.

Comment: post your point shapefile I think is the only solution.

Comment: change the search radius to fixed as well

Comment: Arcmap will use selected points if there is a selection.

Comment: @Frank add this as the answer to we can accept it and close the q. ArcMap will always run on the selected features unless told otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What appears to be happening is that I had only values above -112 selected from an earlier operation a few weeks ago, so when I ran IDW only those were considered. I'd restarted my computer and Arcmap several times, so I didn't think that the layer would retain selection. I also rebooted several times.  In the future I will  make sure that selections are explicitly cleared. I should also have used fixed radius as well. That's a lesson learned